# Static file in django without Using {% static "abc.jpg" %}

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I had static files in django.

Project Structure Sample

[image]

I have project structure like above i want to use js and img from asset folder. How can i do this ? How i can avoid using `{% static  "abc.jpg" %}` ?

Comment: And why you don't want to use `static` tag?

Comment: because i have thousand of images and js file and it can help in reducing time to deploy

Comment: What? How does the static tag affect the time to deploy?

Comment: I will need to change string at thousand of places. Hence Extra time will be required to code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to keep this files in static folder
Keep these files out of templates like

> project_main_folder/static/img/abc.jpg

The **recommended way** is to use **static tag** provided by django.

```
{% static  "abc.jpg" %}
```

---

**Without static tag** you can do this like

```
 <img src="host:port/static/img/abc.jpg" />
```

or

```
<img src="/static/img/abc.jpg" />
```

**This is not recommend.**

Comment: what are changes required in settings.py for this to work. I haven't created static folder too. I am not sure how to handle this.

Comment: For setting files configuration see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40890068/django-1-10-templating-staticfiles-not-showing-any-images/41002929#41002929

Comment: Thanks for answer !!